# This C program does not work properly if I enter letters

Tags: c

If I enter numbers everything works fine. If I  enter letters  the program no longer works. What am I doing wrong?

P.s. Then I will connect other programs in the form of functions and I want them to be able to run from the menu and then return to the selection menu again

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
main ()

{
   int a;
   do {

   
   printf("Enter number of programm: \n 1) First programm \n 2) Second programm \n 3) Third programm \n ");
   scanf("%d", &a);

   switch (a){
   case 1: printf("Start My first programm \n"); break;
   case 2: printf("Start My second programm \n"); break;
   case 3:printf("Start My third programm \n"); break;
   default: printf("There is no such program \n"); break;

   }

   } while (a != -1);

}
```

Comment: What, exactly, does "no longer works" mean?

Comment: scanf %d stops at the first character that is not a digit.  Don't use scanf for user input, use fgets + sscanf.

Comment: You are not checking whether `scanf()` success.  You must do that checking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `scanf("%d", &a)` only gets numbers because

a. `int a` can only store numbers and

b. `"%d"` only gets numbers

To get letter and number input you can do this:

```
char a[100];
fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin); // Store input in a, read the buffer until sizeof(a), and finally read from stdin
```

However, you cannot compare strings in a switch so you will have to use `if` statements and `strcmp` from string.h

Comment: As @stark said, he can then use sscanf to parse an int.